# Forcing child processes to quit after a fork

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create an app that actually forks child processes. the problem is that after all forking is done, I don't need to exit the app to close all child processes.

I'm using the following code:

```
for(i=0;i<tot;i++) {
 switch(PID = fork()) {
    case -1:
      perror("[!] Couldn't fork!\n");
      exit(1);
    case 0:
    //do something
      exit(0);
    default:
      numforks++;
      if (numforks > THREADS)
          for (numforks; numforks > THREADS; numforks--)
              PID = wait(&status);
 }
}

while ((PID = wait(&status)) > 0);
```

the problem is that waiting for PID to finish in the above while, takes longer, as sometimes few children simply hang. How can I implement something that will actually kill the child processes after 3 seconds for example?

I'm aware of kill command but I'm unable to find a way to parse through all forks child processes and send the SIGTERM signal to them.

After some research, i came across to this solution:

```
int mypid;
mypid = getpid();
do {
    pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
     if ( errno == ECHILD ) break;
    if (pid != mypid)
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
} while ( pid > 0 );
```

but the problem is that is not killing only the spawned forks. it kills the parent process as well. Any ideas?

Comment: I want to vote this up for the title alone.

Comment: @TWhite: I had rather the opposite reaction.

Comment: look into the `kill(2)` system call.

Comment: @TWhite I don't get it...

Comment: I think Philipp Murry has your answer. It might be better if your children could exit by themselves though. Maybe you could use non-blocking calls for whatever it is they’re doing, and have them exit after a certain timeout. (Off topic: UNIX is so violent. They could have named it `dismiss` or something, instead of `kill`.)

Comment: @self: At the time of TWhite's comment, the title was "Killing remaining children".

Comment: Is El Bundy behind this question in disguise?

Comment: To expand on @PhilippMurry's comment, you can keep track of the PIDs of the child processes, and signal them via the `kill(2)` syscall.  Perhaps you can give them a few seconds to shutdown cleanly, then use `waitpid()` with the `WNOHANG` option to try to collect each one.  Those that still don't exit can be hit with an unmaskable signal.

Comment: @Unheilig: Do you mean [Ted Bundy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Bundy)? [Al Bundy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Bundy) was the "Married With Children" guy. I don't know that he ever killed any children.

Comment: @FredLarson Didn't even hear of T. Buddy. Ya, I meant Al Bundy, who _loves_ his family :-)

Comment: Not my fault guys, question title was editedby some other dude. He said that there were grammar mistakes, but now i think that I'd rather have grammar errors rather than killing children. :))

Comment: @TWhite that is pretty disturbing that you would think that is funny.

Comment: @self The humor isn't in the death of little ones. The humor is in scrolling through SO question titles and finding Killing remaining children and being reminded, "Oh yeah, forking and killing child processes. I've a dark sense of humor at times and chuckled internally after reading the title then the question.

Comment: Your "solution" is useless because it only sends `SIGKILL` to the subprocesses that exited completely already.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kill()` & a timer to send it after a specified interval.

```
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

ex: `kill(0,SIGTERM);`

if pid equals 0, then sig is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process because when a process is forked, it inherits its PGID from its parent.

Comment: using that actually closed my computer.